# PHP move bold text to array key

Tags: php, arrays, explode, preg-split

I have details array:

```
[info_details] => Array
            (
                [0] => <b>title:</b> this is title
                [1] => <b>name:</b> this is name
                [2] => <b>created</b> this is date
            )
```

and I need to format this array to this:

```
[info_details] => Array
            (
                [title] => this is title
                [name] => this is name
                [created] => this is date
            )
```

so what is the best way to explode bold text?
my code now:

```
foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) {
      $this->__tmp_data['keep'][] = preg_split('/<b[^>]*>/', $value);
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can try this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/tE3oH1/1) with `preg_match()` and `str_replace()`

```
$pattern = "/<b>.+:<\/b>\s?/";

$arr['info_details'] = [
    '<b>title:</b> this is title',
    '<b>name:</b> this is name',
    '<b>created:</b> this is date',
];

$new_arr['info_details'] = [];

foreach($arr['info_details'] as $val){
    preg_match($pattern, $val, $m);
    $new_arr['info_details'][trim(strip_tags($m[0]), ': ')] = str_replace($m[0], '', $val);
}

print '<pre>';
print_r($new_arr);
print '</pre>';
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [info_details] => Array
        (
            [title] => this is title
            [name] => this is name
            [created] => this is date
        )
)
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for. Good job with regex!

Answer (score 2):

PHP has inbuilt function [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to strip HTML tags.

```
   foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) {
            $this->__tmp_data['keep'][] = strip_tags($value);
   }
```

**UPDATE**

```
<?php
$info_details = array
            (
                '<b>title:</b> this is title',
                '<b>name:</b> this is name',
                '<b>created:</b> this is date'
            );
$tmp_data = [];
           foreach ( $info_details as $key => $value ) {
                list($key,$value)=explode('</b>', $value);
               $tmp_data['keep'][str_replace(array(':','<b>'),'',$key)] = $value;
            }
echo '<pre>';
print_r($tmp_data);

?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [keep] => Array
        (
            [title] =>  this is title
            [name] =>  this is name
            [created] =>  this is date
        )

)
```

Comment: and this is not what I need, sorry. this only removes tags, and look again what i need - move everything what is in <b></b> to key and remove it from value

Comment: this will remove the tags but he wants the text in the tags to be used as the key for the remainder of the text in the paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the colon will always be present you can use strip_tags and explode to get what you want.

```
<?php
$info_details = array(
                "<b>title:</b> this is title",
                "<b>name:</b> this is name",
                "<b>created:</b> this is date"
);
$return = array();
    foreach($info_details as $val){
        list ($key, $value) = explode(":",strip_tags($val), 2);
        $return[$key] = $value;
    }

print_r($return);
```

See it live [here](http://3v4l.org/tN02N). Also worth noting that this implementation will remove the : from the array key and strip any html content from the trailing portion of each array element.

If you can't rely on the delimiter to be there you can instead use the close bold tag as your delimiter.

```
<?php
$info_details = array(
                "<b>title:</b> this is title",
                "<b>name:</b> this is name",
                "<b>created</b> this is date"
);
$return = array();
    foreach($info_details as $val){
        list ($key, $value) = explode("</b>",$val, 2);
        $key = strip_tags($key);
        $return[$key] = $value;
    }

print_r($return);
```

or run it [here](http://3v4l.org/CaCUt)

Comment: no, not everytime ":" will be there. so this is not a option :/

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution, but this is hardcode...

```
foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) {
                $this->__tmp_data['keep'][strtolower(str_replace(':', '', strip_tags(@reset(explode('</b>', $value)))))] = trim(@end(explode('</b>', $value)));
            }
```

any other solutions will be accepted, even regex are welcome!

Comment: yes, this is working as well, but the code looks ugly as my gf sister. why do you ask it?

Comment: cause `$this->` is referring to class .. and I didn't see that in your posted code.

Answer (score 0):

reading above comments I guess this is what you needed.

```
<?php

$info_details = array
        (
            '<b>title:</b> this is title',
            '<b>name:</b> this is name',
            '<b>created:</b> this is date'
        );

foreach ($info_details as $value)           
 {          
 $temp = explode("</b>",$value);
$info_details = array(strip_tags(str_replace(":","",$temp[0])) =>$temp[1]);


 }
    print_r($info_details);

?>
```